# Package executables along with Firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

My addon requires to run certain exes and hence I used to package the exes alongwith my addon and put them under the content dir. At the time of running the exe, I used to access the executable by going to <ProfileDir>/extensions/<addon-unique-id>/content/ dir.

While I was trying to make my addon compatible with FF 4, i figured out that now the extensions do not get expanded into a directory under extension/ dir; rather a <addon-unique-id>.xpi file is present there.

Can someone tell me how can I access my exes now?

Thanks
Kapil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it unpack still by [adding a line to your `install.rdf` file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Install_Manifests#unpack).